# Managed Navigation is appending “-2” to new pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Problem is that Managed Navigation is appending “-2” to some new pages.

I've worked out that you must use the "gear" icon and "Add a Page" in order for new pages to be editable for SEO including Managed Navigation (another time draining experience - avoid all other methods!). However, because of that awkwardness, I had to recreate some of the pages, so renamed the old one (eg "X "), created new with the gear Add Page, then gave it a name. Problem - if that name previously existed, the managed navigation switches it to new-page-name-2 instead of just new-page-name. Eg.:

> ```
> Find it at: https://mycompany-public.sharepoint.com/my-new-page-(2)
> ```

Grrr... that will mess up search engines, SEO, all links etc.

Knowing SharePoint, I cleaned out the Recycle Bin, as I realised the original would still be there. But no difference. I do appreciate there is also a second level Admin Recycle Bin, but this being Office 365 not On-Prem, of course I don't have access to that. So, is that the reason it still appends "-2" or "-(2)" etc to the navigation and/or how can we resolve this? TIA,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out there **is** a link to the secondary Recycle Bin - somewhat buried away at the bottom of the Recycle List, not great, but at least it's there! And that does indeed clear it all, so the proper SEO friendly URL can now be created (you may have to get rid of even renamed originals). However, on saving that, it crashes with

> "Term set update failed because of save conflict."

[image]

I couldn't see any old Managed Nav Terms hanging around in the SP Admin Centre, but MS Tech Support through O365 ticket came through and were quick to check the Correlation ID - it was due to cookie clash so advised clearing cookies and temp files, re-logging in. Bit of a PITA but hey, it did the trick, and page all created now... finally!

HTH somebody else!